# Avoiding mouse scrolling in Gedit when editing long documents

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, gedit, plugins

I need a solution specifically for the **Gedit Editor**:

When editing long documents I want to **avoid having to scroll down** with the mouse when hitting the end of the page.

Is there a solution to avoid the mouse? Vim offers the neat **`scrolloff`** feature but I haven't found anything for Gedit ([see here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen)).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1:

<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys do this, but may move you further than you want.

## Option 2:

I don't know if this works in `gedit`, but it does in `kate`, the KDE equivalent. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> scrolls the page down or up, one line at a time. Unfortunately, it doesn't move the cursor with it.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I just tried Ctrl+Arrow in gedit and it's not mapped to anything. That would be a nice feature, especially if the cursor would move along.

Comment: @somethis especially when *all* text editor implement that super-handy feature :'(